# java jMathPlot How to set axis grid increments

Tags: java

How can set I various things in JMathPlot?

```
Plot3DPanel plot = new Plot3DPanel("SOUTH");
plot.setAxisLabels("Periods", "Confidence Level", "VaR");
plot.plotCanvas.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
plot.getAxis(0).setColor(Color.WHITE);
plot.getAxis(1).setColor(Color.WHITE);
plot.getAxis(2).setColor(Color.WHITE);
plot.getAxis(0).setLabelFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20));
plot.getAxis(1).setLabelFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20));
plot.getAxis(2).setLabelFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20));
```

My data on any axis goes from 1.0 to 10.0. How can I force the grid (axis ticks) to have 9 steps, so that I get whole number values on the axis?

Answer (score 1):

The best I found so far is to set fixed bounds:

Examples:

```
// set the X axis to be between 0 and 10
plot.setFixedBounds(0, 0, 10);

// set the y axis to be between 0 and 20
plot.setFixedBounds(1, 0, 20);
```

[setFixedBounds (int axe, double min, double max)](http://jmathtools.sourceforge.net/doc/jmathplot/html/classorg_1_1math_1_1plot_1_1PlotPanel.html#901de823e43b21a0359c14dc82c71af2)

For some reason, that caused the grid to line up properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This example can be usefull for fixed scaling and dynamic update:

```
public  class MyPlot{

static public Plot2DPanel plot1;
static JFrame frame=new JFrame("a plot1 panel");

public MyPlot(){

frame.setSize(400,400);
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setLocation(150,150);
frame.setVisible(true);

plot1 = new Plot2DPanel();

}

// the show Method is to be used for x[] and y[] arrays loading.
public  void show(double [] x,double []y){

plot1.removeAllPlots();
plot1.addLinePlot("my plot",x,y);
plot1.setFixedBounds(0, 0, 1000);// X data range is [0,1000]
plot1.setFixedBounds(1, 0, 1000);// Y data range is [0,1000]
frame.setContentPane(plot1);
frame.repaint();
frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

But the code works well wth Oracle java 6 and 7 but not with 8. The

```
frame.setContentPane(plot1)
```

gives error in case of java 8,  still dont know, till now, how to solve this compatibility issue.